# Android GLSurfaceView stuck

Tags: android, android-camera, glsurfaceview

I use GLSurfaceView to show the camera's data，but if I put camera static for a few minutes and then move it, the GLSurfaceView will not preview any more and stuck,but onDrawFrame() still has response.However if I change the program that GLES20 used, GLSurfaceView work well soon.I don't know where the problem is.Thank for help!

Comment: Start by simplifying things: use a SurfaceView, not a GLSurfaceView. The additional code executed by GLSurfaceView is not at all useful, as you can't draw on a Surface and show a camera preview on it at the same time.

Comment: I'm sorry I not told other details, my code work well in android 5.1 and lower, but it will happen the question above in android 6.0(Nexus 6).So I wanna know is there any differences to use GLSurfaceView or GLES20 in android 6.0

Comment: I'm also observing this issue. After a fairly predictable amount of time (~4.30 minutes on a Nexus 6) I see the preview "freeze". It appears to be swapping between the last 2 frames of video data. I have it plugged into a MediaCodec and that continues to receive frames and encode them successfully. Everything works fine pre-marshmallow.

Comment: @fadden i'm using GLSurfaceView because I want to show camera preview and encode using the MediaCodec (as per the example code in Grafika). Therefore I have a feeling that switching to SurfaceView is impossible if I still want to encode, am I correct?

Comment: @fadden FYI this issue is re-producible in the Grafika application if you remove the code that draws the flashing red box. Looks like only certain models running Android 6.0 are affected. Nexus 6 and Moto X Play are exhibiting this for me.

Comment: One final observation, the output/encoder side suffers from the same issue. Remove the code that draws the moving box and the output video suffers the 'freezing' effect after several minutes too.

Comment: Sounds similar to https://github.com/google/grafika/issues/43 . You'd be better off using Continuous Capture as a model. I used GLSurfaceView for that Activity because there was a stackoverflow question about whether or not it could work; as it happens there's a race condition (https://github.com/google/grafika/issues/36) that can lead to weird behavior. It's possible this is related.

Comment: @DeanWild - We are seeing this exact behavior on a N6 and a few other phones, running marshmallow, also at the 4:30 magical time.  Did you ever find a solution?  We need to support Marshmallow and the GLSurfaceView is more performant than a TextureView for us.

Comment: The link from @fadden, has comments which say to add these lines
`GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);`

`GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`

and that fixes it for us.  thanks!